# odd or even numbers -> repeat until condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know it's absolutely basic but can someone explain to me how to extend code, to repeatedly ask questions about numbers as long as the user enters a nonzero number. But if they enter 0, it should then stop asking and say goodbye.
I've tried to improve it with WHILE but I don't know how to force it to repeatedly ask -  Thank you in advance.

```
print("odd/even checker")

your_number = input("gimme your number ")
number = int(your_number)
left = number % 2

while number != 0:
    if left > 0:
        print("odd")
    else:
        print("even! ")
        break
print("thanks, bye")
```

Comment: There is no WHILE usage shown, so.. not really much to say about that other than “[while] is being used incorrectly”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop.

```py
print("odd/even checker")

while True:
    number = input("gimme your number! :>  ")
    declared_number = int(number)
    if declared_number == 0:
        break

    left = declared_number % 2

    if left > 0:
        print("odd")
    else:
        print("even" )


print("Thanks! Bye!")
```

Comment: ok, now it's clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole code in a while loop and bring `print("Thanks! Bye!")` to the beginning:

```
print("odd/even checker")
while 1 :
    number = input("gimme your number! :>  ")
    declared_number = int(number)
    if declared_number == 0:
        print("Thanks! Bye!")
        break
    left = declared_number % 2

    if left > 0:
        print("odd")
    else:
        print("even" )
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my two guesses would be the use of `while 1` instead of `while True`; and most importantly, this code loops forever: you need a `break` somewhere.

Comment: I didnt down vote you

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
print("odd/even checker")
while True:

    number = input("gimme your number! :>  ")
    declared_number = int(number)
    if declared_number != 0:
        left = declared_number % 2

        if left > 0:
            print("odd")
        else:
            print("even" )

    else:

        print("Thanks! Bye!")
        break
```

Comment: Now this will be complete and good to go

Comment: You changed the logic of the program with that `declared_number > 0` test

Comment: @DivyesshMaheshwari Thanks for down voting my answer

Comment: I didnt vote your ans down

Comment: down voting leads to loss in reputation

Comment: and I am against it

Comment: see my reputation is same as 360

Comment: @sal please tell me how it changed the logic

Comment: Your code only checks for positive numbers. The OP doesn't have that check in place, and it's not needed.

Comment: any better now !

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do this, but the core remains that you need to get the input from the user inside the loop, and then you can check for a condition to exit. One way would be something like:

```
print("odd/even checker")

# Predefine a value that will pass the condition check in the `while` below
declared_number = -1

while declared_number != 0:
    # from now on, the value will be updated by the user
    number = input("gimme your number! :>  ")

    declared_number = int(number)
    left = declared_number % 2
  
    if left > 0:
        print("odd")
    else:
        print("even" )

print("Thanks! Bye!")
```

Another way is to start an infinite loop, and use `break` to exit if the condition is not met:

```
print("odd/even checker")

while True:  # loop forever
    number = input("gimme your number! :>  ")
    declared_number = int(number)
    
    if declared_number == 0:
       # explicitely break the loop
       break

    left = declared_number % 2

    if left > 0:
        print("odd")
    else:
        print("even" )

print("Thanks! Bye!")
```

Comment: These two are not equivalent. In the first example, a `0` input does not terminate the loop until after it has already printed "even". In the second, it breaks the loop immediately.

Comment: True. I would argue that 0 is even though.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. My point is simply that the two behave differently -- I'm not saying that one is better or worse.

Comment: No worries and thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

A basic approach to this question can be

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while (num != 0):
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        print('even')
    else:
        print('odd')
    num = int(input('Enter a number again: '))
if num == 0:
    print('Goodbye')
```

This outputs

```
Enter a number: 5
odd
Enter a number again: 2
even
Enter a number again: 0
Goodbye
```

The if statement outside while loop is optional. The code can also be written as

```
1 num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
2 while (num != 0):
3     if (num % 2 == 0):
4         print('even')
5     else:
6         print('odd')
7     num = int(input('Enter a number again: '))
8 print('Goodbye')
```

This is because when the control will come to line 8, the `num` variable will be surely 0.